Ignore the same exception multiple times and continue with code
I'm currently working on a Python 3.12.3 plugin for QGIS 3.36.2 that adds two toolbars and a layer at different stages of its code. In unload I want to remove all of them with e.g.:
self.toolbar.deleteLater()
del self.toolbar

Depending on when the user unticks the plugin, it's possible that at least one of these elements hasn't been created yet or has even been removed again already. If that's the case, then both if not self.toolbar and if self.toolbar in locals() (loops over everything, so probably not the fastest either) throw an error (and getattr seems to be buggy, according to the comments here):

AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'toolbar'

It looks like the only way to check if one of these elements still exists to delete it, is the use of:
try:
    self.toolbar.deleteLater()
    del self.toolbar
except AttributeError:
    pass

There are 3 elements that I have to check and I can't deal with all of them within the same try because it's going to jump right to the except block once the error is thrown and skip the rest of the code, of course.
What is a more "readable" way of doing this that doesn't require a separate try ... except for each of the elements?

How about adding self.toolbar = None after del self.toolbar (and also in your __init__) and then put the destructor code in an if block?

@couteau del self.toolbar happens in unload, what's the point of setting it to None afterwards if it's already marked for gc? Initializing the 3 elements with None should prevent the exception (probably would be okay to do that in initGui too, right?), thanks, but won't I need 3 different ifs then (instead of 3 trys) or is there anything to prevent that in Python?

There may be no point if you don't expect the user to reactivate your plugin after deactivating it, though if you set the three attributes to None in initGui instead of __init__ as you suggest, that will take care of that scenario, too. Yes, it will require three if statements, but there's nothing wrong with that. And if your concern is readability, it's probably more readable than three try...except blocks and more readable than trying to come up with some way to put them all within a single block.

@couteau Sorry, I somehow missed your second comment. So: Initialize my "self" UI elements with None in __init__/initGUI and set the reference back to None after del-ing them, then they won't cause the error if I do if self.toolbar in unload?
